# Sorting rownames of a data frame based on a separate vector

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, match

I'm ordering the rows of a data frame based on my row names and an external vector. The vector can be shorter than the number of rows.

I've tried different combinations of match and order, but they don't want to take rownames(df) as an argument, or it creates a vector of factors instead

```
df <- data.frame(info = c("cluster1","cluster7", "cluster1", "cluster3"),row.names = c("gacg","cggt","cgat", "ccat"))

vector <- c("gacg","cgat","cggt")

       info
gacg   cluster1
cggt   cluster7
cgat   cluster1
ccar   cluster3
```

I tried variants of this solution:

```
df2<-df[order(match(df$rownames,vector)),] #produces some type of vector of factors
```

I would like a data frame that is ordered with the rownames in the same order as the vector, and mismatching rows where the vector data frame is shorter than the vector should be placed at the end.

```
       info
gacg   cluster1
cgat   cluster1
cggt   cluster7
ccar   cluster3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use :

```
df[order(match(rownames(df), vector)), , drop = FALSE]
```